# Jquery: find textbox and dropdown value in table through $.each loop

Tags: jquery

during table iteration by jquery i want to read value from textbox and dropdown. i want to access textboxes and dropdown by id. i tried this code but not getting desired output. here is full code.

```
<table id='sample'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Vehicle          
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id='txtFname' name='txtFname'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  id='txtLname' name='txtLname'>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>          
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id='txtFname' name='txtFname'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  id='txtLname' name='txtLname'>          
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id='vehicle'>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>          
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">sample footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>    
</table>

$('#sample tr').each(function() {
    alert($(this).("input[id^='txtFname']").val());

});
```

where i made the mistake? thanks

### EDIT

i want to iterate table when button click.........but still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
$('#sample tr').each(function() {
    alert($(this).find("input[id='txtFname']").val());
  return false
});
    }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/mgbqhL7v/6/

Comment: `$(this).find("input[id^='txtFname']").val();` use this.

Comment: frankly speaking invalid markup usage as per standards you can't/shouldn't use same ids for multiple elements.

Comment: it's a bad approach to repeat the textbox ID's multiple times

Comment: replace it with class or name

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgbqhL7v/5/

Comment: and to be frank it's a bad approach to prefix name attribute with 'txt' etc. The name attribute should be meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `.find()`

Use this

```
$(this).find("input[id^='txtFname']").val();
```

in your `alert`

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/mgbqhL7v/2/)**

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/mgbqhL7v/4/)**

Comment: i use your code but alert showing undefined.see https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/8L6nuft8/2/

Comment: just update the post.......see edit portion and js fiddle link. still not working. i want to show textbox value after setting textbox value at runtime.

Comment: Then cover that code in button click. This code is working https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/mgbqhL7v/4/

Comment: You can show textbox value at runtime and still will be able to show those values.